# What Eclipse plugin is available for integrating Tomcat 7?

Tags: tomcat7, eclipse-europa

What Eclipse plugin is available for integrating Tomcat 7 in its IDE?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Eclipse **[WTP (Web Tools Platform](http://www.eclipse.org/webtools/)** (since [WTP 3.2](http://www.eclipse.org/webtools/releases/3.2.0/NewAndNoteworthy/server.php) according to [bug 308916](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=308916)) supports Tomcat 7.

Simply [pick the right distro](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/moreinfo/compare.php).

[image]