# How to install tomcat plugin in Eclipse

Tags: java, tomcat, eclipse-plugin

I am using Eclipse as my SDK for web project and I need tomcat integration with Eclipse. I am on my Ubuntu machine. How can I do the integration stuff? How and from where I can download and install tomcat plugin?

Comment: I think there is a problem with Google if you haven't found a half-decent site that talks about either Eclipse WTP or Sysdeo. Or you are simply lazy. Obligatory link: [What Eclipse plugin is available for integrating Tomcat 7?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3794064/what-eclipse-plugin-is-available-for-integrating-tomcat-7)

Comment: ##Install Apache Tomcat plugin in eclipse
1. Copy URL https://devtools.his.de/tomcatplugin/updatesite/ -> Open Eclipse -> Goto Help -> Install new Software 
2. Paste URL at Work with textbox -> After search results -> Select Tomcat Plugin -> Click on Next button -> Next -> 
3. At Review Licenses window -> Select I accept the terms of license agreements -> Finish
4. We can see Installation progress in Progress view (Window -> Show view -> General -> Select Progress -> Click on Open button
5. Once Installation done a new popup will be displayed -> Click on Restart Now button

Answer (score 12, accepted):

you have to do several things:

1. download and extract Tomcat
2. Install the WTP tools using Eclipse built-in update mechanisms or download the Eclipse Java EE prepackaged build: http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-java-ee-developers/indigor
3. Configure Tomcat in Eclipse

The following screenshot shows my Eclipse configuration (Ubuntu Natty 11.04, eclipse Helios 3.6, Tomcat 7.0.12):

[image]

Answer (score 25):

1. Download the [Eclipse Tomcat Plugin](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/eclipse-tomcat-plugin) from Marketplace
2. Go to `window->Preference`.Find Tomcat configuration from the left
   panel and configure it.

Answer (score 4):

You can download Eclipse for Java EE

Answer (score 0):

This solution worked for me:

1. Download zip file of the Tomcat Plugin from https://sourceforge.net/projects/tomcatplugin/
2. Install the .zip file from Eclipse. You could use the guide: [1.makesure your .zip file is an valid Eclipse Plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5482554/how-to-install-plugin-for-eclipse-from-zip) found in another question.